# lamba expression nested .select and using navigation properties in lower level

Tags: entity-framework, linq

```
    var discount= q.Products
        .SelectMany(qp => qp.ProductMods)
        .SelectMany(qpm => qpm.ModDiscounts)
        .Where(qmd => qmd.DiscountID == discountid)
    .Sum(qmd => qmd.DiscountValue  * 

    (q.Products.SelectMany(qpm => qpm.ProductMods).Select(qpm => qpm.Quantity)).FirstOrDefault()

    );
```

I would like to do the above like this:

```
    var discount= q.Products
        .SelectMany(qp => qp.ProductMods)
        .SelectMany(qpm => qpm.ModDiscounts)
        .Where(qmd => qmd.DiscountID == discountid)
    .Sum(qmd => qmd.DiscountValue  * qpm.Quantity);
```

but I do not have access to qpm.Quantity value because it's higher level.

any suggestions?

Comment: can't be done with .include

Comment: What is the relationship between ProductMods and ModDiscounts, one to many? do you have navigation properties in both sides?

Comment: ProductMods can have one or more moddiscounts for each productmods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship between `ProductMods` and `ModDiscounts` is one to many you should have a navigation property in `ModeDiscount` to `ProductMod`, so your query could be like:

```
  var discount= q.Products
        .SelectMany(qp => qp.ProductMods)
        .SelectMany(qpm => qpm.ModDiscounts)
        .Where(qmd => qmd.DiscountID == discountid)
        .Sum(qmd => qmd.DiscountValue  * qmd.ProductMod.Quantity);
```

Comment: yes, i do!  didn't realize i could go backwards like that.  THANKS.